# Radio Button Confirmation, Cancel and Ok Doing the same thing

Tags: javascript, confirm

I am stuck on a project that I am doing at college and the confirmation which I am trying to do return the same thing when you click 'OK' and 'Cancel'
I want it to untick the radio button when I press Cancel and I want it to keep the radio button ticked when I press OK

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function getConfirmation()
{
    var retVal = confirm("Your Level of Entry is A2, is this correct?");
    if (retVal == true)
    {
        alert("Your Level of Entry is A2!");
        return true;
    } 
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Set the `checked` property of the button:

```
function getConfirmation()
{
    var retVal = confirm("Your Level of Entry is A2, is this correct?");
    if (retVal)
    {
        alert("Your Level of Entry is A2!");
        return true;
    } 
    else
    {
        document.getElementById('radioButton').checked = false;
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your JS [as it is](http://jsfiddle.net/AstroCB/9sGJd/) works.

Nothing in there actually changes the state of the radio button, though.

To do that, you can use the `checked` property.

Say you had this:

```
<input type="radio" name="group1" checked="true" id="a2"/>A2
<input type="radio" name="group1" id="not"/>Not A2
```

You could add `document.getElementById("not").checked = true;` in your `else` block to check the other radio button if the confirmation is cancelled:

```
function getConfirmation() {
    var retVal = confirm("Your Level of Entry is A2, is this correct?");
    if (retVal) {
        alert("Your Level of Entry is A2!");
        return true;
    } else {
        document.getElementById("not").checked = true;
        return false;
    }
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/AstroCB/9sGJd/2/)